# Why is this Excel macro works on a computer and not on another?

Tags: excel, vba

I know my code looks like Frankenstein for take bits around the web, but it does work on my computer. Yet, when I try to run it on another computer (that has the same Excel 2016 version), it gives me

> run-time error '9': subscription out of range

Why?

I have been doing some iterations such as removing activeworkbook to deal with various error it was giving but the error keeps changing. In addition, this time, the VBA debugger does not even give me a yellow line to check.

```
Sub CombineAll()

    'Stop, delete sheet and activate Alerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("Programmation générale").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Insert a new worksheet. Assign it to a name. Place it before Index
    Set NewWs = Worksheets.Add(Before:=Worksheets("Index"))
    NewWs.Name = "Programmation générale"

    'Loop to copy worksheets
    NextRow = 1
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not NewWs.Name = ws.Name Then
            If Not Sheet1.Name = ws.Name Then
                finalRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1
                ws.Cells(2, 1).Resize(finalRow, 14).Copy NewWs.Cells(NextRow, 1)
                NextRow = NextRow + finalRow
            End If
        End If
    Next ws

    'Copy header
    Sheet3.Range("A1:N1").Copy
    NewWs.Range("A1").Rows("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlDown


    'Select the new worksheet and transform into table
    NewWs.Select
    Dim src As Range
    Set src = Range("B5").CurrentRegion
    Set NewWs = ActiveSheet
    NewWs.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Source:=src, _
    xlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes, tablestyleName:="TableStyleMedium15").Name = "ProgrammationGenerale"

    'Arrange the table to specifications
    Range("ProgrammationGenerale[#All]").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

    ActiveSheet.Columns("A:N").AutoFit

    Dim finalRowTable As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    finalRowTable = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A1:A" & finalRow).EntireRow.AutoFit
    For i = 2 To finalRow
        If Range("A" & i).EntireRow.RowHeight < 27 Then
            Range("A" & i).EntireRow.RowHeight = 27
        End If
    Next if

    ActiveSheet.Range("D:F").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ActiveSheet.Range("H:J").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Programmation générale").ListObjects("ProgrammationGenerale").Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add _
            Key:=.Parent.ListColumns("Début_Date").DataBodyRange, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With


    'Arrange for printing
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperLegal

End Sub
```

Comment: Step through the code using `F8` on the other computer. At what line do you get the error?

Comment: My guess is the culprit is that `TableStyleMedium15`...

Comment: where does the other computer get to in the code?? debug and let us know..